# Update shape on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry

I have a circle on google maps and I have a function which increases the radius. How do I update the circle on the map?

```
    this.markerBoundary.radius = rd; //New radius assigned

    //I need to update the shape here but setMap does not work
    this.markerBoundary.setMap(this.gmap);

    this.bounds = this.markerBoundary.getBounds();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `setRadius`-method instead to set the radius-property:

```
this.markerBoundary.setRadius(rd);
```